# How do I know what have been changed by pd.to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume it is a large database load from a csv, I don't know there is a "Hello" in date column.

```
df = {"No.": [1, 2, 3, 4],
      "Date": ["17/4/2022", "18/4/2022", "Hello", "19/4/2022"]}
```

Output:

```
No. Date
1   17/4/2022
2   18/4/2022
3   Hello
4   19/4/2022
```

After `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True, errors="coerce")`

The "Hello" become "NaT".

Output:

```
No. Date
1   17/4/2022
2   18/4/2022
3   NaT
4   19/4/2022
```

How do I know there was a "Hello"?

How do I know what value have been changed by pd.to_datetime?

Comment: So, do you want to keep the string as it is and convert all dates?

Comment: If you don't save it yourself, there's no way to recover the original value. Maybe you should put the converted time in a different column.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I want to extract a list of value that would be changed

Comment: @RyanYCT so you want all strings, right? Bcuz the dates are already in datetime format

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Yes, I expect a list just containing "Hello"

Comment: @RyanYCT I have provided an answer. Let me know if it solves your query or do you need something else?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish well, no, they may be strings as well. So they won't be in datetime format.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right I missed that but it looks like OP wanted all the strings and not datetime.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is ok. After getting a "Changes" column that can be .tolist() and discard all duplicates then keep what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you want to know the changes and get only strings. You can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"No.": [1, 2, 3, 4],
      "Date": ["17/4/2022", "18/4/2022", "Hello", "19/4/2022"]})
df['Changes'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x if x.isalpha() else "No Change")
```

Output:

```
   No.       Date    Changes
0    1  17/4/2022  No Change
1    2  18/4/2022  No Change
2    3      Hello      Hello
3    4  19/4/2022  No Change
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to achieve what you're trying to do - you could join two dataframes by index:

```
df_1.join(df_2, on = df_1.index, lsuffix = '_df_1', rsuffix = '_df_2')
```

So the resulting table could look like this

[image: Joined tables]

Comment: after that, you could extract only `Date_df_1` and `Date_df_2` columns, to have some kind of dictionary of what values were changed.